# Blank UI when adding charts to a container in codename 1

Tags: achartengine, codenameone

How to add 4 charts on the same form using a tablelayout.
i tried adding a chart to a container nothing comes out. please help

Comment: Show what you have tried so far. Any error messages? Show them.

Answer (score 0):

The charts return no preferred size so the layout code sizes them to zero. This was fixed for the next update but you probably won't get what you want here.

I'm assuming that what you want to use is a 2x2 grid layout which will give every cell exactly the same size. Alternatively you can add the charts with a `TableLayout` constraint that gives it 50% width/height so it occupies the space properly.